# max/min-width using maximal possible width

Tags: html, css, width

I'd like to ask how to create a footer bar in CSS that will have minimum width (let's say 650px) and will strech depending on window size but only to some point (let's say 1024px).

what I mean is when window size is for example 1280px bar should have been 1024px, when is window 720px bar should have been 720px and when window is 500px the scroll bar should appear.

here is my html:

```
<footer id="footer">
<div class="inner">
    <hr>
    <ul class="menu">
            <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">News</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
    <div class="copy">Copyright © 2015 All rights reserved.</div>
</div>
</footer>
```

thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The code below should work

```
#footer{
width:100%;
max-width:1024px;
min-width:650px;
}
```

Comment: this isn't working it always shrink to smallest posible because "menu" and "copy" aren't too big to fill whole footer div...

Comment: Do you have a sample of your code.  There may be a conflict because the code above should work properly

Comment: yeah, now it's working I had there some garbage that I removed thanks... :)

Answer (score 0):

This should work.

```
#footer {
  min-width: 650px;
  max-width: 1024px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

James' answer is almost correct, all you need is a display rule,

```
#footer{
width:100%;
max-width:1024px;
min-width:650px;
display: block;
}
```